# Trim list of sharing apps in ICS

Tags: share-menu

Things like sharing photos come to mind. When I view a photo and click Share, the list can get pretty bloated depending on what apps I have installed. Is it possible to trim the list of apps down or disable them from appearing on this list?

Annoyingly, many of my most useful and frequented apps have been bumped down on the list and I now have to scroll to select an app.

Comment: Is your device rooted? I do not know for sure, but in that case I might have an idea...

Comment: Isn't that one of the new features of ICS? My sharing list is trimmed. For example see Figure 1 from http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

Comment: The device is not rooted (yet). I'm unwilling to make that jump until I know that I really want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Andmade Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andmadesoft.share) -- an app that claims to replace your share list with a completely customizable one, as the following screenshots show:

[image: Andmade Share: Deactivating unwanted] [image: Andmade Share: Organize sort-order]

As you see, you not only can get rid of unwanted entries -- but also re-organize the order of those left, so you can have your most-used on top.